# Tangential and Normal acceleration of a particle moving in a plane curve in cartesian coordinates

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, vector-analysis, curvature

How did the author compute highlighted term 2 from the highlighted  term 1 in the following answer to the given question?

If $\rho =\frac{d\psi}{ds}$, then term 2 should be $\upsilon^2\frac{d\hat{T}}{d\psi}\rho$ but instead it was written $\frac{\upsilon^2}{\rho}\frac{d\hat{T}}{d\psi}$

How is that computed ? How to compute radius of curvature?

$note=\frac{d\hat{T}}{ds}=\kappa\hat{N}$

[image: part1]

[image: part2]

Comment: It should be $\rho=\frac{ds}{d\psi},$ hence $\frac {d\psi}{ds}=\frac 1 {\rho}.$

Comment: @Pythagoras, If that is the case, then term 1 should be $\upsilon^2\frac{d\hat{T}}{ds}\frac{ds}{d\psi}$ isn't it?

Comment: There are no mistakes in either (1) or (2). The typo is in the parenthetical remark: Namely $\frac{d\psi}{ds}$ should be $\frac 1 {\rho}$ instead of $\rho.$.